# multiple arguements with colon

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to figure out how to run a script with multiple arguments but each argument needs to have a colon in-between them..so for example:

setup.exe SERVERNAME:PORT

The problems I want to over-come are:

1.The problem is that a user could enter in a number of arguments

2.The arguments entered has to have a colon in between them and must be complete as SERVERNAME:PORT - is there a way of doing this?

I have the below written as draft and am not too sure if it will give me what I want?

```
argsCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

If argsCount < 1 then
    WScript.Echo "Error no arguments selected - usage: script.vbs <SERVERNAME>:<PORT>, <SERVERNAME>:<PORT>, <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> etc"
    WScript.Quit
Else
    For Each arg In args
        setup.exe <IP>:<PORT>
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to drop the , and to use a RegExp:

```
Option Explicit

Dim args : Set args = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed

If args.Count < 1 then
    WScript.Echo "Error no arguments selected - usage: script.vbs <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> etc"
    WScript.Quit
Else
    Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
    r.Pattern = "^\w+:\d+$"
    Dim a, m
    For Each a In args
        Set m = r.Execute(a)
        If 1 <> m.Count Then
           WScript.Echo "Bingo:", a
        Else
           WScript.Echo "setup.exe", m(0).Value
        End If
    Next
End If
```

output:

```
cscript y.vbs
Error no arguments selected - usage: script.vbs <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> <SERVERNAME>:<PORT> et
c

cscript y.vbs server:123 a:0 0:a "nice try:4711" abc:abc abc:000
setup.exe server:123
setup.exe a:0
Bingo: 0:a
Bingo: nice try:4711
Bingo: abc:abc
setup.exe abc:000
```

**Version 0.2:**

Using Split(OneAndOnlyArg, ",") to feed the RegExp:

```
Option Explicit

Dim args : Set args = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed

If args.Count <> 1 then
    WScript.Echo "Error no arguments selected - usage: script.vbs <SERVERNAME>:<PORT>,<SERVERNAME>:<PORT>,<SERVERNAME>:<PORT> etc"
    WScript.Quit
Else
    Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
    r.Pattern = "^\w+:\d+$"
    Dim a, m
    For Each a In Split(args(0), ",")
        Set m = r.Execute(a)
        If 1 <> m.Count Then
           WScript.Echo "Bingo:", a
        Else
           WScript.Echo "setup.exe", m(0).Value
        End If
    Next
End If
```

output:

```
cscript y.vbs server:123,a:0,0:a,abc:abc,abc:000
setup.exe server:123
setup.exe a:0
Bingo: 0:a
Bingo: abc:abc
setup.exe abc:000
```

Note that spaces will break this approach.

Comment: this is REALLY good...unfortunately, the setup.exe file I use HAS got to have the , and I just realised there cannot be a space between them..so, it must be <SERVERNAME>:<IP>,<SERVERNAME>:<IP>.....any chance of doing it like this please?